# Возникает ошибка

Tags: php

Возникает вот такая ошибка, подскажите из-за чего:

```
Warning: Unknown: Your script possibly relies on a session side-effect which existed until PHP 4.2.3. Please be advised that the session extension does not consider global variables as a source of data, unless register_globals is enabled. You can disable this functionality and this warning by setting session.bug_compat_42 or session.bug_compat_warn to off, respectively in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: как раз у него повыше версия, используется какаято хрень, которая было ДО версии 4.2.3
зыж по фотографиям не лечим :)

Comment: код сессии в студию, отладкой займитесь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А все потому, что у вас скорее всего какая-то ВАША переменная имеет имя `$_SESSION` и вы ее используете... А так делать плохо...

Варианта 2:
 1. не использовать ВАШИ переменные с именем `$_SESSION`
 2. вырубить ошибки :)

```
ini_set('session.bug_compat_warn', 0);
ini_set('session.bug_compat_42', 0);
```

Comment: и вообще, гугление по "Your script possibly relies on a session side-effect which existed until PHP 4.2.3" дает сразу все отвтеты на вопросы.